# Problems encountered in the use of torch.corrcoef in the case of origin

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch(1.10), we can use torch.corrcoef to Estimates the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient matrix.
But there is an obvious problem, when a row is all 0, there will be a nan value, how can I modify it to solve it, I think I can make the similarity of this row and other rows all 1, but I don't know How to do it.
[nan value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kzgk.png)

Comment: Can you give us a *minimal* input and the output you are currently getting with nan values?

Comment: import torch

weight = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

output = torch.corrcoef(weight)
print(output)

Comment: the result is tensor([[1.0000,    nan],
        [   nan,    nan]])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.